# search filter in React giving error while trying to use state hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

- I am try to add search feature to an existing lists of robot names.
- In order to do so I am trying to useState hooks. I have an App component and Header component which has the input tag for search field.
- Error I am getting is 'InputEvent' is assigned a value but never used.
  Below is the code for App component (main component).

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Robo from "./Robo";
import { robots } from "./robots";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const InputEvent = (e) => {
    const data = e.target.value;
    setQuery(data);

    const extraction = robots
      .filter((curElem, index) =>
        robots[index].name.toLowerCase().includes(query)
      )
      .map((curElem, index) => {
        return (
          <Robo
            key={robots[index].id}
            id={robots[index].id}
            name={robots[index].name}
            email={robots[index].email}
          />
        );
      });
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header query={query} InputEvent={InputEvent} />
        <div className="robo-friends-container">{extraction};</div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
export default App;
```

Child component

```
import React from "react";
import "./header.css";

const Header = ({ query, InputEvent }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="headerText">ROBO FRIENDS</div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="lname"
          name="lname"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={query}
          onChange={InputEvent}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: could you pls add a sample data of the `robots` file

Comment: Sure, here it is : 
```
export const robots = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clementine Bauch',
    username: 'Samantha',
    email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
    username: 'Karianne',
    email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org'
  }]
```

Comment: Ok.. thanks.. will add my answer asap.. there are few suggestions to change the code and work in optimized way.. will add those in my answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer in stackblitz app

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-robots-filter?file=App.tsx,Robo.tsx,Header.tsx,robots.ts

I have altered the code a bit.. you can fork the project and play with it..

You can add debounce option to your input, which prevents unwanted re-renders

Adding the changes:

```
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(undefined);
  const [filteredRobots, setFilteredRobots] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(query);

    const filteredRobots = robots.filter((robot) => {
      return robot.name.includes(query);
    });

    if (filteredRobots.length) {
      setFilteredRobots(filteredRobots);
    }
  }, [query]);

  const onQueryChange = (e) => {
    const data = e.target.value;
    setQuery(data);
  };

  const renderRobots = () => {
    if (!query || !query.length) {
      return <p>{'Search to find Robots'}</p>;
    }

    if (filteredRobots && filteredRobots.length && query && query.length) {
      return filteredRobots.map((filteredRobot) => (
        <Robo
          key={filteredRobot.id} //id is unique key in your data
          name={filteredRobot.name}
          id={filteredRobot.id}
          email={filteredRobot.email}
        />
      ));
    }

    return <p>{'No Robots Found'}</p>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header query={query} InputEvent={onQueryChange} />
      {renderRobots()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Problems in your code:

1. `Const InputChange` is a function that can be used as prop for any React component .. but you have added `InputChange` inside the `InputChange` named function itself which is incorrect
2. `Extraction` is a jsx variable which is created from `Array.filter`.. on each item, filter passes a item[index] to the filter function.. you dont want to do `robots[index].name.toLowerCase().includes(query)`.. instead you could have done `curElem.name.toLowerCase().includes(query)` and same applies for `Array.map`